# Simple c++ input fuction

Tags: c++, string, integer

I am new to c++ and i was wondering if the program asks you to input the fraction (a/b)  how do you remove that dividing sign ("/") to get the values of a and b?

for example:

```
int x1, x2, y1, y2;
cout << "The programk performs arithmetic operations on two rational numbers." << endl;
cout << "Enter a rational number <a/b> : ";
cin >> // what can i do to get the value of a for x1 and b for x2??
```

Thank you for your time, any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Read a character and ignore it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>

std::vector<std::string> Split(const std::string &s, char delim)
{
    std::vector<std::string> elems;
    std::stringstream ss(s);
    std::string item;
    while (std::getline(ss, item, delim))
        elems.push_back(item);
    return elems;
}

int main() 
{
    std::cout << "Enter a/b:" << std::endl;
    std::string input;
    std::cin >> input;
    auto ab = Split(input, '/');
    int a = std::stoi(ab[0]);
    int b = std::stoi(ab[1]);
    std::cout << a << "/" << b << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use indexOf to find where "/" is, and the create a substring for the left part, and a substring for the right part. You can then parse the left and right part to numbers, and calculate the result.